# MySql calculate multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have code below and in my query but the results it gives me is way off chart, so I thought maybe my calculation is wrong. `The Logic` is to have multiple column `sum` `minus` and `times` to eachother and the result based on my database numbers has to be `4.581.709.50` but I get something like `164.610.000`

```
 SUM(c.gaji_pokok + c.uang_makan + c.tunjangan + c.kendaraan + c.overtime + c.komisi + c.lain_lain + c.cuti - 
                m.pot_absen_hari * m.pot_absen_rate - IFNULL(g.pot_absen_hari * g.pot_absen_rate, 0) - CONCAT((c.uang_makan)/0.25)*0.05 -
                n.pot_komisi_dl - n.pot_komisi_p312 - n.pot_komisi_mteg - IFNULL(g.pot_komisi_kasbon, 0) - q.bpjs4 - o.pot_ppn_21pt - o.pot_pinjaman - o.pot_ppn21 - o.pot_bayar_bonus - 
                o.pot_bayar_thr - c.cuti) as bulan_ppn21,
```

## Query

```
SELECT
        a.nip,

            SUM(c.gaji_pokok + c.uang_makan + c.tunjangan + c.kendaraan + c.overtime + c.komisi + c.lain_lain + c.cuti - 
            m.pot_absen_hari * m.pot_absen_rate - IFNULL(g.pot_absen_hari * g.pot_absen_rate, 0) - CONCAT((c.uang_makan)/0.25)*0.05 -
            n.pot_komisi_dl - n.pot_komisi_p312 - n.pot_komisi_mteg - IFNULL(g.pot_komisi_kasbon, 0) - q.bpjs4 - o.pot_ppn_21pt - o.pot_pinjaman - o.pot_ppn21 - o.pot_bayar_bonus - 
            o.pot_bayar_thr - c.cuti) as bulan_ppn21,
            
            IFNULL((
            CASE
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=50000000)
            THEN  (0.05*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)))
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=250000000)
            THEN  (0.15*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.15)-(q.jht*12)))
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=500000000)
            THEN  (0.25*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.25)-(q.jht*12))) end),0) as tahun_pph21,
        IFNULL((
            CASE
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=50000000)
            THEN  (0.05*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)))
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=250000000)
            THEN  (0.15*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.15)-(q.jht*12)))
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=500000000)
            THEN  (0.25*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.25)-(q.jht*12))) end) -(
            CASE
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=50000000)
            THEN  (0.05*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)))
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=250000000)
            THEN  (0.15*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.15)-(q.jht*12)))
                WHEN ((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)<=500000000)
            THEN  (0.25*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.25)-(q.jht*12))) end)/12,0) - (
            CASE
                WHEN (((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate))<=50000000)
            THEN  (0.05*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate)))
                WHEN (((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate))<=250000000)
            THEN  (0.15*((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate))-5000000)
                WHEN (((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate))<=500000000)
            THEN  (0.25*(0.03*(c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate))-55000000)*1.2
                WHEN (((c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate))<=500000000)
            THEN  (0.25*(0.03*(c.gaji_pokok * 12)-((c.gaji_pokok * 12)*0.05)-(q.jht*12)-(r.pt_kp_rate))-55000000)*1.2 end) as tot_pph21
FROM `t_pegawai` a
        LEFT JOIN t_penggajian_karyawan c ON c.nip=a.nip
        LEFT JOIN t_departemen d ON d.id_departemen=a.id_departemen
        LEFT JOIN t_jabatan e ON e.id_jabatan=a.id_jabatan
        LEFT JOIN t_perusahaan f ON f.kode_unitbisnis = a.unit_bisnis
        LEFT JOIN absensi k ON k.pin = a.pin
        LEFT JOIN t_periode l ON l.nama_periode=c.bulan  and YEAR(l.periode_start) = c.tahun
        LEFT JOIN t_potongan_absen m ON m.nip=a.nip and m.nip=c.nip and  m.bulan = l.id_periode and m.tahun = YEAR(l.periode_start)
        LEFT JOIN t_potongan_gaji g ON g.nip=a.nip and g.nip=c.nip and  g.bulan = l.id_periode and g.tahun = YEAR(l.periode_start)
        LEFT JOIN t_potongan_komisi n ON n.nip=a.nip and n.nip=c.nip and n.bulan = l.id_periode and n.tahun = YEAR(l.periode_start)
        LEFT JOIN t_potongan_ppn o ON o.nip=a.nip and o.nip=c.nip and  o.bulan = l.id_periode and o.tahun = YEAR(l.periode_start)
        LEFT JOIN t_jenjang_bpjs q ON q.nip=a.nip  and q.tahun = YEAR(l.periode_start)
        LEFT JOIN t_ptkp r ON r.pt_kp_name=a.status_ptkp
WHERE l.id_periode='8' AND f.kode_unitbisnis ='PJS-001' and k.Tanggal >= l.periode_start and k.Tanggal <= l.periode_end
GROUP BY a.pin
```

**Any suggestion on calculation way to make it right?**

Comment: *..  - CONCAT((c.uang_makan)/0.25)*0.05 - ..* String function CONCAT() is strange in numeric context and seems to be excess.

Comment: @Akina please share your solution it might works :)

Comment: If this solves your problem then you may create self-answer (I consider this a typo).